# Worker node doesn't trigger Jenkins job in queue even when available

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins

This question could seem similar to other questions but I tried everything and nothing worked for me that's why I'm asking specific question for my case.

I am running Jenkins jobs using Pull request builder in a master - worker system. I have 2 worker with 2 executors each. Master doesn't have any executor. I have 2 freestyle jobs A and B. My plan is to run job A and B concurrently (whenever PR is open/modified) in a worker node but I cannot run my job A/B concurrently in a node. Currently, by default, my job A is tied to one worker node and job B is tied to another worker node. All other jobs are in queue which delays my test execution.

I looked around for different plugins - Node and Label parameters, distributed builds, job restrictions. I tried labelling the jobs and node but jobs didn't trigger. So, not sure what's the problem as I don't see any errors in logs may be I'm not using plugins in a proper way. Can someone please let me know what is the good way of the dealing my situation?

Comment: Verify if **Disable concurrent builds** or **Throttle concurrent builds** or **Lockable resources** is enabled in the job configuration page.

Comment: Throttle concurrent builds and lockable resources aren't enabled. I haven't checked 'Execute concurrent builds if necessary'. I'm not sure If I have to enable this.

Comment: @DibakarAditya - I used throttle concurrent builds where total builds is 2 and 1 build per node. I believe this should resolve my build queue issue but it didn't.

Comment: This appears to be a peculiar issue. When your builds are queued, do they say - waiting for an available executor or the job is already running? Do you have quiet period selected in the job configuration? Also how is your PR trigger set up in the job configuration and executors configured?

Comment: @DibakarAditya "#2​16 (pending—Build #215 is already in progress)" this is what I see on the build queue. No quiet period is selected in job config. I'm using GitHub Pull request builder which has cron job set to check for PRs. I have a master and 2 worker nodes in aws ec2. I added 4 executors in one node. "Use this node as much as possible" option is selected in node.

Comment: Ok, you said you used throttle concurrent builds with max total concurrent builds 2 and max concurrent builds per node as 1. Here, 1 implies only one build per node, not 1+1. Similarly, 2 implies 2 builds at a time. Interestingly enough, 0 implies unlimited. You might want to play around with these options. Also make sure that **Prevent multiple jobs with identical parameters from running concurrently** is not selected.

Comment: Thanks. it worked

Comment: Great that you could make it work.